# The issue with live search in Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livesearch

I'm using Livewire and encountering an issue with my live search. Every time I enter a name into the search bar, the live search doesn't work immediately; instead, I have to click the pagination button several times. Can you help me?

my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\mahasiswa;

use Livewire\Component;

use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Search extends Component

{

public $search = "";

use WithPagination;

protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

public function render()

{

$mahasiswa = mahasiswa::where('nama', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->paginate(5);

return view('livewire.search', [

'mahasiswa' => $mahasiswa,

]);

}

public function updatingSearch()

{

$this->resetPage();

}

}
```

my views:

```
t

<div>

<div class="my-3 p-3 bg-body rounded shadow-sm">

<!-- FORM PENCARIAN -->

<div class="pb-3">

<input type="text" class="form-control me-2" name="search" wire:model.debounce.500ms="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"  id="liveSearchInput">

</div>

<!-- TOMBOL TAMBAH DATA -->

<div class="pb-3">

<a href='{{url('mahasiswa/create')}}' class="btn btn-primary">+ Tambah Data</a>

</div>

<table class="table table-striped">

<thead>

<tr >

<th class="col-md-1">No</th>

<th class="col-md-3">NIM</th>

<th class="col-md-4">Nama</th>

<th class="col-md-2">Jurusan</th>

<th class="col-md-2">Aksi</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

@foreach ($mahasiswa as $item)

<tr wire:key="item-{{ $item->id }}">

<td>{{$mahasiswa->firstItem() + $loop->index}}</td>

<td>{{$item->nim}}</td>

<td>{{$item->nama}}</td>

<td>{{$item->jurusan}}</td>

<td>

<a href='{{url('mahasiswa/'.$item->nim.'/edit')}}' class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>

<form onsubmit="return confirm('Yakin menghapus data?')" class="d-inline" action="{{url('mahasiswa/'.$item->nim)}}" method="POST">

@csrf

@method('DELETE')

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Del</Del></button>

</form>

</td>

</tr>

@endforeach

</tbody>

</table>

{{$mahasiswa->links()}}

</div>

</div>
```

I want the data to appear immediately without having to click the pagination button multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Livewire 3 *wire:model* is always deferred,  to get the desired result you need *wire:model.live* :

```html
<input type="text" wire:model.live.debounce.500ms="search">
```

[Here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#wiremodel) the documentation

Comment: Thank you, now the live search is running smoothly.